# No thread seems to be executing

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I am trying to solve the producer consumer problem using pthreads and semaphores. At the moment, neither of the threads seem to execute and even main isn't printing out a printf, it seems like the process is waiting for input. (so all that happens is, blinking cursor, then I press ctrl+c to end the process because nothing is happening). I have tested get_rand_num and that works. I am compiling with clang -Wall -std=c99 -lpthread -o randnumgen randnumgen.c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include "sema.c"

typedef struct buffer {
    uint64_t *buffer;
    int max_size;
    int min_fill_lvl;
    uint64_t *first;
    uint64_t *last;
    int size;
    semaphore produce; 
    semaphore consume;
} buffer;

void *producer();
void *consumer();
uint64_t get_rand_num();
void init_buffer();
void cleanup_buffer();
void put_buffer();
uint64_t get_buffer();
int exit1=0;
buffer buf;

int main(){

    initialize(&buf.produce, 0);
    initialize(&buf.consume, 0);

    pthread_t producerThread;
    pthread_t consumerThread;
    printf("test");
    pthread_create(&producerThread, NULL, producer, (void *) &buf);
    pthread_create(&consumerThread, NULL, consumer, (void *) &buf);

    vacate(&buf.produce);

    pthread_join(producerThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumerThread, NULL);

    return 1;

}

void *producer(buffer *buf){
    printf("in producer");
    init_buffer(&buf, 2, 1); 

    while (1){
        procure(&buf->produce);
        uint64_t ret = get_rand_num();
        put_buffer(&buf, ret);

        vacate(&buf->consume);
    }

    cleanup_buffer(&buf);
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

void *consumer(buffer *buf){
    printf("in consumer");

    while (1){
        procure(&buf->consume);
        uint64_t ret = get_buffer(&buf);
        printf("%i", (int) ret);

        vacate(&buf->produce);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

uint64_t get_rand_num(){

    FILE *rand = NULL;

    rand = fopen("/dev/random", "r");

    uint64_t num;

    //static const size_t size = sizeof(uint64_t);

    fread(&num, sizeof(num), 1, rand); //returns -1 if fails i believe

    //printf("%i\n", (int) num);

    return num;

}

void init_buffer(buffer *buf, int max, int min){
    buf->buffer = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t) * max);

    buf->size = 0;
    buf->min_fill_lvl = min;
    buf->max_size = max;
}

void cleanup_buffer(buffer *buf){
    free(&buf->buffer);
}

void put_buffer(buffer *buf, uint64_t *num){

    if (buf->size < buf->max_size){
        *(buf->last++) = *num;
        buf->size++;
    }
    printf("successfully placed num in buffer");


}

uint64_t get_buffer(buffer *buf){

    if ((buf->size - 1) <= buf->min_fill_lvl){
        buf->size--;
        int ret = *buf->first;
        buf->first++;
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my semaphore code:

```
// semaphore setup
void initialize(semaphore *sp, int startVal){
    pthread_mutex_init(&sp->lock, NULL);
    sp->vacancy = startVal; //starting value for semaphore
    pthread_cond_init(&sp->condition, NULL);
}

//destroys semaphore
void destruct(semaphore *sp){
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&sp->lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&sp->condition);
}

//waits until semaphore is available
void procure(semaphore *sp){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sp->lock);
    while(sp->vacancy <= 0){
        pthread_cond_wait(&sp->condition, &sp->lock);
    }
    sp->vacancy--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sp->lock);
}

//increments vacancy value signalling that a position has been freed
void vacate(semaphore *sp){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sp->lock);
    sp->vacancy++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&sp->condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sp->lock);
}
```

Comment: You have several problems in your code, some of which your compiler should have told you. (1) the interfaces of your thread functions are wrong, they should correctly be (foreward) declared as receiving `void*`. No need to cast a pointer to `void*`. `printf` wouldn't print anything until it hits the first `'\n'` or you do an explicit `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: @JensGustedt fflush(stdin) leads to undefined behavior...

Comment: @Lundin, yes I know, was just a typo, I meant `stdout`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this applies to clang as well, but for gcc you ought to use `-pthread` for compiling  (as well).

Comment: Also it is a good idea to debug code using a debugger, stepping through the code mostly gives one good impression of what is really happening.

Comment: as stated by @jens, simply add a '\n' to the end of each string to be printed.

Comment: function: init_buffer(), the fields last and first are not initialized (should be 0).  function: get_buffer(), The operation will fail and continue to fail as soon as the min-fill-level value is reached.  function: put_buffer(), the operation will fail and continue to fail as soon as the max-fill-level value is reached.  I suggest redesigning the put and get functions for continuous operation.   Then add the missing fields to the initialization function.

Comment: something to think about.   What happens when the get_buffer() starts reading from areas in the buffer that the put_buffer() has not yet written?